# Scanning a .txt file to get the sum of a column WITHOUT an array

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My assignment is to get the sum of a column and divide it by 10 to get the average without using an array.

> My text file:

```
86 89 98
78 83 93
93 76 89
95 80 93
64 79 95
89 63 73
71 89 96
75 87 78
88 92 91
93 82 87
```

---

I have this but understandably doesn't seem the most effective.

```
    File f = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
    int columns = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        columns = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(columns);
        scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextInt();
        sum += columns;
    }
    scan.close();
    System.out.println("Average of Column 1: " + sum / 10);
```

> Output: Average of Column 1: 83

How can I make this better?

Comment: Why don't you just repeat the same logic for the other 2 columns? Make 3 variables: sum1, sum2, sum3 and just repeat what you already do.

Comment: 1. Replace the 2nd and 3rd ```nextInt```  with ```nextLine``` 2. Don't hard-code the divisor

Comment: It is fine. Limited though as it only picks up the first column. There are other ways to a very similar thing.

Comment: By the way, use [`Math.addExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#addExact(int,int)) to detect if [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) occurs.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I got it going for all 3 columns but I noticed that the last digit of the columns isn't being added to the total. For instance column 1 stops adding at 88 instead of adding the final digit 93

Answer (score 0):

```
final File textFile = new File("input.txt");
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(textFile))
{
    if (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        try (Scanner columnIteratorScanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine()))
        {
            int column = 0;
            while (columnIteratorScanner.hasNextInt())
            {
                columnIteratorScanner.nextInt();
                try (Scanner fileContentScanner = new Scanner(textFile))
                {
                    int rows = 0;
                    int sum = 0;
                    while (fileContentScanner.hasNextLine())
                    {
                        rows++;
                        try (Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(fileContentScanner.nextLine()))
                        {
                            for (int col = 0; col < column; col++)
                            {
                                lineScanner.nextInt();
                            }
                            sum += lineScanner.nextInt();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.printf("Column %d average: %d%n", column, sum / rows);
                }
                column++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```